# How to calculate x and y of any object inside an image when stretched?

Tags: image-processing, scale-space

Suppose a image has

```
Height = 200px;
Width = 100px;
```

A point in that image which has

```
Y axis = 40px
X axis = 30px
```

Now if I resize that image:

```
New Height = 300px;
New Width = 150px;
```

> Is there any formula to calculate new Y and X axis of that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the stretch is simply linear and consistent across the image, then the displacement of the point is proportional to the [magnification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification#Magnification_as_a_number_.28optical_magnification.29) factor.

For the X-Axis:

- At $100px$ width, the point was at $30$
- At $150px$ width, where would the point be? (Let's call this our unknown $x$).

$$x=\frac{150}{100} \times 30 = 45$$

Similarly, for the Y-Axis, the point will now be at $60$.

Hope this helps.