# Normalization of an image in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, normalization

If I have an image whose range is from $-18.3667\cdot10^{-5}$ to $9.3127$, how could I normalize it on the same gradient so that they fall between a specific range, say fro $0$ to $255$?

Comment: That is really a question that you should be able to answer yourself with a sheet of paper, a pencil, and three lines of writing stuff down.

Comment: ...but if you need some sort of hint, you might want to take a look at [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34037/how-to-calculate-x-and-y-of-any-object-inside-an-image-when-stretched/34038#34038)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **shift**: put the minimum to $0$, by compensating the actual minimum $m=−18.3667⋅10^5$ for every pixel: $p\to p - m$. Now your pixels are between $0$ and a new maximum $M = 9.3127 - m$. Finally you want the final image in $[0,255]$. The second operation is **scale**: multiply by something, so that $0$ remains at $0$, and $M$ is cast to $255$. So you have to multiply by $255/M$.

Comment: Thanks, I do it. 
`[Sx, Sy]=size(T);` % T the image that we want to normalize

`m=min(min(T));

M=max(max(T))- m;`

% shifting
`for i=1:Sx,
   for j=1:Sy,
     T(i,j)=T(i,j)-m;
   end
end`

%Scaling
`T=T*255/M;`

Comment: All the operations are linear, so you can do this directly on the matrix, no loop: `T = rand(3,3); Tnew = 255*(T-min(T(:)))/(max(T(:))-min(T(:)));`